# Upnp for Rpi zero w with pi cam

Tags: raspbian, networking, pi-zero-w, internet, media-server

I am trying to implement the upnp on my RPI ip cam. The goal is to make it portable so I can use it anywhere (with just the wifi SSID and pwd) without having to port forward everytime I have to deal with a new router.

Yes : I am trying to access the pi cam feed outside of my network without having to port forward all the time.

I very new but so far, I have been able to stream in local only. I also know some media server like miniDLNA that are using upnp. I don't know how to stream the live feed on that media server.

My question is where do I start from there? As anyone done this before? Is there any useful tutorial on that so far? I have been googling but no luck so far.